Не загружаеться графическое окружение в arch linux
использовал арч с kde plasma, хотел установить yay для использования пакетов AUR:
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
cd yay/
makepkg -si

все зависло, после перезагрузки старт системы остановился на "starting terminate plymouth boot screen"
включил вместо sddm, lightdm появилось окно выбора пользователя но на рабочий стол не зашло.
Как восстановить систему?

Зависло именно во время выполнения makepkg или после чего-то другого?

@andreymal после 'makepkg -si' перестал работать терминал, новый не запускался

makepkg не может просто так взять и сломать терминал, так что наверное проверьте здоровье накопителя например

@andreymal линукс на виртуальной машине, врядли это что-то с накопителем

Ну тогда просто логи читайте, начать можно с systemctl --failed например

@andreymal UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTIONS   0 loaded units listed

может у вас там "случайно" место закончилось на виртуальном диске (там много зависимостей могло подтянуться) ? сам makepkg запускается от обычного пользователя, то есть на саму систему это никак не могло повлиять. п.с. устанавливать проще yay-bin особенно под виртуалкой.

@arhat Выделял для диска 40гб, занято 11

40 гиг под раздел или под диск ?

под весь виртуальный диск

ну а что с разделами ? какие выделены разделы и сколько там места ?

@arhat sda1-700мб под ефи, sda2-1гб раздел подкачки, и sda3-все остальное место

в TTY консоль зайти можешь и глянуть что показывает команда df -h ?  да и зачем подкачка виртуалке, мало выделили оперативки виртуалке ?

@arhat https://imgur.com/a/K5Lnfvi

вроде всё должно хватать, а просто нового пользователя пробовали создать и зайти через него ?

@arhat всё также, полазил немного на форумах, думаю проблема с xorg, попробовал xorg -configure https://imgur.com/a/AojM5pn
